# imacros extract 2 parts of data + concatenate constant save to file javascript

Tags: javascript, save, constants, imacros

I need to extract 2 parts of data in 2 different columns then concatenate with a string and save to file. see below example how i am expecting data to be saved.

I am getting syntax errors and it may not be producing expected result. i spotted errors with comments below.

```
//each row is written as below
//part1 = 182.30.2.129; 
//part2 = ":"; 
//part3 = 8080; 
//finalvalue = 182.30.2.129:8080 - like this it will write row by row

var jsLF="\n";
var ret=null;

var proxynovaurl; //open url
proxynovaurl  =  "CODE:";
proxynovaurl +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
proxynovaurl +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
proxynovaurl +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
proxynovaurl +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/anonymous-proxies/" + jsLF; 

var proxynova; //extract part #1 value
proxynova =  "CODE:";
proxynova += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
proxynova += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
proxynova += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
proxynova += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
proxynova += "SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}" + jsLF; //** Potential error in syntax **//
proxynova += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + jsLF;
//proxynova += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\  FILE=ip-address.csv" + jsLF;

var proxynovamid; //use constant for part #2 value
proxynovamid =  "CODE:";
proxynovamid += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
proxynovamid += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
proxynovamid += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
//proxynovamid += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
proxynovamid += "SET !VAR2 ':'" + jsLF; //** Potential error in syntax **//
//proxynovamid += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + jsLF;

var proxynova1; //extract part #3 value
proxynova1 =  "CODE:";
proxynova1 += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
proxynova1 += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
proxynova1 += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
proxynova1 += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
proxynova1 += "SET !VAR3 {{!EXTRACT}}" + jsLF; //** Potential error in syntax **//
proxynova1 += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + jsLF;

var proxynovafinal;
proxynovafinal =  "CODE:";
proxynovafinal += "ADD !EXTRACT {{VAR1}} + jsLF; //** Potential error in syntax **//
proxynovafinal += "ADD !EXTRACT {{VAR2}} + jsLF; //** Potential error in syntax **//
proxynovafinal += "ADD !EXTRACT {{VAR3}} + jsLF; //** Potential error in syntax **//
proxynovafinal += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\  FILE=ip-address.csv" + jsLF;

iimPlay(proxynovaurl); //launch url

for(var i=1;i<=236;i=i+6) //1st loop extract 1st part of value
{
iimDisplay(i);
iimSet("i", i);
iimPlay(proxynova);
iimSet("i",i);

iimSet("j",i+1);
//for(var j=17;j<=37;j=j+5) 
//{
//iimDisplay(j);
//iimSet("j", j);
iimPlay(proxynovamid); //extract 2nd part of value
iimPlay(proxynova1);   //extract 3rd part of value
iimSet("j",i+1);
iimPlay(proxynovafinal); //write final concatinated value to file (Part1+part2+part3)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add quotes at the end in proxynovafinal block
2. remove single quotes in proxynovamid

Comment: i did silly mistake again. than for spotting up. it is getting partial data but my loop stuck. i will post another question may be you can answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090789/imacros-javascript-conditional-skip-of-data-extract  -