# imacros javascript conditional skip of data extract

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements, imacros, skip

while executing below loop fails as soon as a advertisement is encountered. Site purposefully put random advertisement. is it possible to handle it with #EANF# not sure how to code it. please help. Something like this.

```
//if(text=="#EANF#" || text=="undefined" || text==null || text=="" )
//{
////handle the loop
//}

var jsLF="\n";
var ret=null;

var proxynovaurl; //open url
proxynovaurl  =  "CODE:";
proxynovaurl +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
proxynovaurl +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
proxynovaurl +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
proxynovaurl +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/anonymous-proxies/" + jsLF; 

var proxynova; //extract part #1 value
proxynova =  "CODE:";
proxynova += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
proxynova += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
proxynova += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
proxynova += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
proxynova += "SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}" + jsLF;
proxynova += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + jsLF;
//proxynova += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\  FILE=ip-address.csv" + jsLF;

var proxynovamid; //use constant for part #2 value
proxynovamid =  "CODE:";
proxynovamid += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
proxynovamid += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
proxynovamid += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
//proxynovamid += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
proxynovamid += "SET !VAR2 :" + jsLF;
//proxynovamid += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + jsLF;

var proxynova1; //extract part #3 value
proxynova1 =  "CODE:";
proxynova1 += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
proxynova1 += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
proxynova1 += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
proxynova1 += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
proxynova1 += "SET !VAR3 {{!EXTRACT}}" + jsLF;
proxynova1 += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + jsLF;

var proxynovafinal;
proxynovafinal =  "CODE:";
proxynovafinal += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}" + jsLF;
proxynovafinal += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR2}}" + jsLF;
proxynovafinal += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR3}}" + jsLF;
proxynovafinal += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\  FILE=ip-address.csv" + jsLF;

iimPlay(proxynovaurl); //launch url

for(var i=1;i<=236;i=i+6) //1st loop extract 1st part of value
{
iimDisplay(i);
iimSet("i", i);
iimPlay(proxynova);
iimSet("i",i);

iimSet("j",i+1);
//for(var j=17;j<=37;j=j+5) 
//{
//iimDisplay(j);
//iimSet("j", j);
iimPlay(proxynovamid); //extract 2nd part of value
iimPlay(proxynova1);   //extract 3rd part of value
iimSet("j",i+1);
iimPlay(proxynovafinal); //write final concatinated value to file (Part1+part2+part3)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use iimGetExtract http://wiki.imacros.net/iimGetExtract 
to get extracted value after each block of code which extracts the data (remove SET !EXTRACT NULL to keep the data), after that you can use extracted data as you wish.
here is example

```
var proxynova1; //extract part #3 value
proxynova1 =  "CODE:";
proxynova1 += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
proxynova1 += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
proxynova1 += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
proxynova1 += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
proxynova1 += "SET !VAR3 {{!EXTRACT}}" + jsLF;
var qqq = iimGetExtract();
if (qqq == '#EANF#'){ data not found flow}
```

Comment: I think this website made us impossible to predict extract logic.